# how do I run a C code using VS Code after installing gcc?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

After installing gcc on my Windows PC, I tried running a simple C program but, I keep getting an error message saying

> Unable to find executable for 'C\Users\Asi Polcarp\Desktop\Cprograms<executable.exe>'

This message is from VS Code.

```
# include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    printf("welcome");
}
```

Comment: I need more context. Have you compiled it? Can VSCode see your gcc? How do you build it? How are you trying to run it?

Comment: The tutorial on Using GCC with MinGW (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) contains a fairly complete guide on how to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to put path of the GCC file to the folder environmental variables and try to compile it in the folder where you have actually put the path address.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).